# Entropy of a van der Waals' gas

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, entropy

I would like to ask how I could derive the entropy change $dS$ for a van der Waals' gas.
I think I would need to use the total differential of entropy and then use the Maxwell relation shown below.
Firstly, I would write down the total differential for $S$.
$$dS = \left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T dV + \left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V dT$$
Then I would substitute $\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_T$ by $\left(\dfrac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_V$ and $\left(\dfrac{\partial S}{\partial T}\right)_V$ by $\left(\dfrac{C_V\ \partial T}{T\ \partial T}\right)$.

But then I am stuck. May anyone gives me some hints on how to derive $dS$ for a van der Waals' gas?

Comment: Oh yes, I am sorry. Let me change it back. Thanks!

Comment: Derive the partial derivation dp/dT  atV=const for the vdW equation. Be aware it will not be probably explicitly resolved.

Comment: But then I do not have $C_V$... That's where I am stuck.

Comment: You can derive it from the experimental Poisson coefficient for real gasses $\gamma=\frac{CV+R}{CV}$. Or use tabelized heat capacities. But all the task may  easily lead to numerical solutions only.

Comment: BTW you should always include all relevant circumstances into the question, to avoid guessing, wrong assimptions and clarifications.

Comment: You need to know Cv which, for a Van Der Waals gas is independent of specific volume.  So it would be the same as the ideal gas Cv.